# How to update the class instance attribute

Tags: python

With one car brand 'VW' and three models I want to create a single instance of class `Car` and only update its`models` list attribute with a new models:

```
class Car(object):
    cars = {}

    def __init__(self, brand, model):
        self.brand = brand
        self.models = [model]
        self.cars[brand] = self

    def __new__(self, brand, model):
        if brand in self.cars:
            car = self.cars[brand]
            if not model in car.models:
                car.models.append(model)
                print '....appended model %r to brand %r. result: %r' % (model, brand, car.getModels())
            return car
        else:
            return super(Car, self).__new__(self, brand, model)

    def getModels(self):
        return self.models


cars = []
for i in range(3):
    car = Car(brand='vw', model='model_%s' % i)
    if not car in cars:
        cars.append(car)


for car in cars:
    print car.getModels()
```

So, the goal is `print car.getModels()` to print:

```
['model_0', 'model_1', 'model_2']
```

Instead, I am getting only the last model: `['model_2']`

Where is the error in a code?

Comment: Well, that's definitely not how you implement `__new__`. Note, `__new__` is the *constructor*, the instance doesn't exist, as your code seems to imply. Check out [this](http://howto.lintel.in/python-__new__-magic-method-explained/) for a relatively good overview.

Comment: Since `__init__` would be called every time that models would be set to `[model]`, and `model_2` is the last model.